# Ip адресация

Tags: ip

```
Почитал про организацию ip-адресации, и не могу понять...
Вот посмотрел я на свойства своего роутера и увидел(ip конечно же поменял немного)
ip - 34.85.112.30
маска - 255.255.255.255
1)Это получается я подключен к сети класса A, и весь ip адресс это сплошной адресс сети, адреса узла нету?
-------------------------
набрал ipconfig в командной строке и вижу
ipv4 - 192.168.0.4
маска - 255.255.255.0
1) вот этот ipv4 он же локальный адрес и для каждой машины, подключенной к моему роутеру, будут даваться различные локальные адреса?
2) и получается на любом компьютере локальный адрес будет представлять собой что-то вроде 192.168.0.x?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ip - 34.85.112.30 - IP Вашего роутера, он уникален в сети интернет, т.е. у Вас белый IP
192.168.0.4 - IP подсети Вашего роутера. Да, все устройства подключенные к роутеру будут иметь адрес вида 192.168.0.x и к ним нельзя обратиться из другой сети по этим адресам, для этого необходимо на роутере прокидывать порты а обращаться на 34.85.112.30

Comment: "он уникален в сети интернет", а как так получается, ведь во всемирной сети наверняка больше компьютеров чем 255*255*255*255, и ip сможет повторяться получается он ен уникален?

Comment: В пределах одной сети не могут существовать два одинаковых адреса.
IP адрес это четыре блока с набором символов от 1 до 255, и того выходит довольно таки не маленькое число комбинаций (255^4 = 4 228 250 625). Так же стоит учитывать то, что некоторые интернет провайдеры предоставляют по умолчанию "серые" IP адреса, которые доступны только в под сети.
PS IPv4 уже почти исчерпал себя, поэтому вводят IPv6 

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C8%F1%F7%E5%F0%EF%E0%ED%E8%E5_IPv4-%E0%E4%F0%E5%F1%EE%E2

Comment: тогда последний вопрос, почему маска 255.255.255.255, где адрес узла?

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8